# Get the ID in a child entity of NDB GAE Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, key, app-engine-ndb

I'm going in circles on **getting the id** of NDB Datastore.

I have setup the `webapp2.RequestHandler` to catch the email and get the ID. Basically my goal is to delete an entity, but if I pass the email address to get the ID of the entity, I'm stump, because it gives me results I was just getting. I used ID instead of `key_name`.

I tried **finding the ID by querying via email**, but it seems like using query does not have a method attribute to find the id.

```
def get(self,email):
  user = users.get_current_user()
  if user:
    user_key = ndb.Key('UserPrefs',user.email())
    contacts = Contact.query(Contact.email==email,ancestor=user_key)
    self.response.write(contacts.id) # there is no attribute such as Contact.id
```

I tried to **find the ID by getting the key**, but when I displayed the key, it showed me whatever value I have in the `email` variable

```
def get(self,email):
  user = users.get_current_user()
  if user:
    user_key = ndb.Key('UserPrefs',user.email())
    contact_key = ndb.Key('Contact',email,parent=user_key)
    self.response.write(contact_key.id())
```

**Real Question:** So, given that **I do not have the ID**, how do I find the **correct ID** inside an entity if I saved my entities via id and not key_name?

Here are the mixture of codes that I'm trying out.

```
def get(self,email):
  user = users.get_current_user()
  if user:
    user_key = ndb.Key('UserPrefs',user.email())
    contact_key = ndb.Key('Contact',email,parent=user_key)
    contacts = Contact.query(Contact.email==email,ancestor=user_key)
    contact = contacts.get()
    contact_key.delete()
    # self.response.write(contact.name) # this works
    self.response.write(contact_key.id()) # this does not work because I do not have the entity id, and I'd like to get it blindfolded. Is there a way?
```

Here is my Model for Contact.

```
class Contact(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  phone = ndb.StringProperty()
  email = ndb.StringProperty()
  dateCreated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
  dateUpdated = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now=True)
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Note:** the identifiers, which are `id`, `key`, `urlsafe`, or `value` (for the query) should be passed from the HTTP Request by webapp2.RequestHandler from a parsed url or HTTP POST, GET, PUT, or DELETE.

If you do not have any **identifiers** or **values** passed from an HTTP request, it could be difficult to access the **specific entity** (or the record). So, it is important to take note to pass a form of identifier or value to access the **specific entity** (or the record in database terms).

So, you can do the following to get the id:

**Access by value:**

```
def get(self,email):
  user = users.get_current_user()
  if user:
    user_key = ndb.Key('UserPrefs',user.email())
    contacts = Contact.query(Contact.email==email,ancestor=user_key)
    contact = contacts.get()
    id = contact.key.id() # this access the entity id directly because you have the data.
    self.response.write(id)
```

**Access by urlsafe:**

```
def get(self,urlString):
  user = users.get_current_user()
  if user:
    contact_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=urlString) #urlString refers to the key of contact
    contact = contact_key.get()
    id = contact.key.id() # this access the entity id directly because you have the data.
    self.response.write(id)
```

**Access by HTTP POST Request:**

```
def post(self):
  user = users.get_current_user()
  if user:
    user_key = ndb.Key('UserPrefs',user.email())
    email = self.request.get('email')
    contacts = Contact.query(Contact.email==email,ancestor=user_key)
    contact = contacts.get()
    id = contact.key.id() # this access the entity id directly because you have the data.
    self.response.write(id)
```

Comment: I'm downvoting because you're saying you can't access the entity id.
You can use `contact.key.id()` to get the id.  The rest of the answer about how to delete the entity is correct.

Comment: I found it out just later as I continued programming. Will change the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities#Overview) state:

`The identifier may be either a key "name" string assigned by the application or an integer numeric ID generated automatically by the Datastore.`

Since you are defining the `name` property on your `Contact` class, this is used as the identifier. (You don't want that because in real world different users can have same names)

So if you want NDB to generate numeric IDs for your entities, rename the `name` property to something else, e.g. `username`.

**Update:** let's go step by step:

Problem with the first example is that you are trying to get `id` on the [Query](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/queryclass). Query class has no `id` property defined on it. You should call `get()` on it:

```
# get() or fetch() should be called on query to return some data
contacts = Contact.query(Contact.email==email,ancestor=user_key).get()
self.response.write(contacts.id) # there is no attribute such as Contact.id
```

Problem with the second piece of code is that you are just [initialising a Key](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass#Constructors) and providing email as `id` - the second param of constructor is the `id` and you are providing email as value. Hence you are getting the email out. Also, there is no database operation here.

Comment: The docs does not seem to state how to get the `contact_key.id()` without supplying the id or key_name in getting the `contact_key`. Is there anyway to get the `contact_key.id()` without knowing the id or ID/Name number of the entity?

Comment: Entities are identified by key, which contains identifier, which is either name (string) OR ID (numeric), not both. Since you used name, there is no ID.

Comment: A the docs state, the property named `name` is treated specially - if you define it then NDB will use it as identifier.

Comment: The "real question" states getting the `contact_key.id()`. I understand that `ndb.Key("UserPrefs",user.email(),"Contact",contact_key.id())` can probably give me the `contact_key.id()`. But what if I don't know what the `contact_key.id()` is? How do I get the `contact_key.id()`? Is there a way to get it so I can use `contact_key.delete()`? Using `contact_key.id()` gives me the value of `email` coming from `ndb.Key("UserPrefs",user.email(),"Contact",email)`. `contact_key.id()` does not give me the `ID/Name` value. Instead, it gives me the value of what I gave it, which was `email`, unexpectedly.

Comment: I explained that there is no `id` IF you defined the special `name` property on your entity class. It's either `id` or `name` not both. Docs clearly state that and I even quoted the relevant section.

Comment: I understand that we can only choose one: id or key_name. I also stated that I chose to use the id and not the key_name. So, how do you get the id blindfolded? Can you do that? Yes, you are right. My purpose is to access the Entity in Datastore to get the Entity id. So, you're saying that in ndb, you should not access or get the id of the entity? but instead create another attribute named id in Contact?
**If I can not get the Contact entity id, I can not use contact_key.delete()**.